# combine two select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two select query like

```
select name1,age1 from table1
```

output :

```
+--------+------+
| name1  | age1 |
+--------+------+
| ravi   |   25 |
| rakhav |   12 |
| joil   |   10 |
+--------+------+

select color,no from table2
```

output

```
+--------+----+
| color  | no |
+--------+----+
| red    |  3 |
| yellow |  4 |
+--------+----+
```

i want the output like

```
+--------+------+--------+----+
| name1  | age1 | color  | no |
+--------+------+--------+----+
| ravi   |   25 | red    |  3 |
| rakhav |   12 | yellow |  4 |
| joil   |   10 |        |    |
+--------+------+--------+----+
```

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` your two select statements are going to return rows in random order. Which rows of table2 go with which rows of table1?

Comment: If you are just trying to get two totally unrelated pieces of information with one query, don't. Use two queries. Otherwise explain how they are related.

Comment: yes totally unrelated pieces...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from
(select name1, age1, row_number() over(order by age1 desc) as rn from table1) as t1
left join
(select color, no, row_number() over(order by no) as rn from table2) as t2
on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

try `select t1.*, t2.* from table1 t1, table2 t2`

Comment: its geting like cross join

Comment: Yes, but how you wanna combine the records from 2 tables?